# Correlation range for third random variable given two correlation results

Tags: correlation, random-variable

I have three random variables $f$, $k$, $l$ and $corr(f,k)=0.9$, $corr(f,l)=0.9$. How do I find the maximum and minimum boundaries of the $corr(k,l)$?

I think the upper boundary would be 1 and this may be the case when $k=l$. But how do I find out the lower bound of these two random variables?

Answer (score 2):

Adaptation of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/586142/43949).

Let $X,Y,Z$ be random variables. Without loss of generality we may assume they have mean zero and variance one, since correlation is invariant under shifting and scaling.

Let $\rho_{XY}, \rho_{YZ}, \rho_{XZ}$ be the pairwise correlations (which are equal to covariances since everything has variance one).
One can check that $O_{XY} := X-\rho_{XY} Y$ and $O_{YZ} := Z - \rho_{YZ} Y$ are each uncorrelated with $Y$.

Then,
\begin{align}
\rho_{XZ} &= \text{Cov}(X,Z)
\\
&= \text{Cov}(\rho_{XY} Y + O_{XY}, \rho_{YZ} Y + O_{YZ})
\\
&=\rho_{XY} \rho_{YZ} \text{Cov}(Y,Y) + \rho_{YZ} \text{Cov}(O_{XY}, Y)
+ \rho_{XY} \text{Cov}(Y, O_{YZ}) + \text{Cov}(O_{XY}, O_{YZ})
\\
&= \rho_{XY} \rho_{YZ} + \text{Cov}(O_{XY}, O_{YZ}).
\end{align}
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$|\text{Cov}(O_{XY}, O_{YZ})|
\le \sqrt{\text{Var}(O_{XY}) \text{Var}(O_{YZ})}=\sqrt{(1-\rho_{XY}^2)(1-\rho_{YZ}^2)}$$
where the last step is due to
$$\text{Var}(O_{XY}) = \text{Var}(X - \rho_{XY} Y)
= \text{Var}(X) + \rho_{XY}^2 \text{Var}(Y) - 2 \rho_{XY} \text{Cov}(X,Y)
= 1-  \rho_{XY}^2.$$

Thus, we arrive at
$$|\rho_{XZ} - \rho_{XY} \rho_{YZ}| \le
\sqrt{\text{Var}(O_{XY}) \text{Var}(O_{YZ})}=\sqrt{(1-\rho_{XY}^2)(1-\rho_{YZ}^2)}.$$

In your case, the remaining probability is in the interval with endpoints $0.9^2 \pm (1-0.9^2)$, i.e. $[0.62,1]$.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please elaborate this part: `One can check that OXY:=X−ρXYY and OYZ:=Z−ρYZY are each uncorrelated with Y.`?

Comment: @AK88 Compute $\text{Cov}(O_{XY}, Y)$ by plugging in the definition of $O_{XY}$ and using linearity properties of covariance.